# How many times this formula will be used?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two equations:

**if** $(b \ge x)$ do this assignment: $b = b-x$

**else** do this assignment: $b = w - (x - b)$

I know that $w > b$, $w > x$ and $x > 0$.

**The question is:**

Given the values of $b$, $x$ , $w$ and $s$, I want to know how many times the second equation will be used if I repeated the process $s$ times.

Sorry it's my first question here :)

My way to solve something like this:

$b - x$ will be repeated $s$ times so I know that the value of $b$ will be decreased $s*x$ times , but I can't complete this formula to get the answer, please help!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: have you tried solving the problem on your own? show us your computation and thoughts - otherwise it is unlikely that people will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are going to count steps we better number the $b$'s. Your algorithm defines the recursion
$$b_{k+1}:=\cases{b_k-x\quad&$(b_k\geq x)$\cr b_k-x+w&$(b_k<x)$\cr}\qquad(k\geq0)\ .$$
After $s$ steps we have
$$b_s=b_0- sx+ nw$$ with an unknown number $n\geq0$. This $n$ is the number of times the second rule was invoked. We need $n$ correction steps $+w$ if $n-1$ or less of them would leave us in the negative:
$$b_0-sx+(n-1)w<0\ ,\tag{1}$$
but $n$ of them make $b_s\geq0$:
$$b_0-sx +nw\geq0\ .\tag{2}$$
The inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ can be rewritten as
$$n-1<{sx-b_0\over w}\leq n\ ,$$
and this is equivalent with
$$n=\left\lceil{sx-b_0\over w}\right\rceil:=\min\left\{k\in{\mathbb Z}\>\biggm|\>k\geq{sx-b_0\over w}\right\}\ .$$

Comment: I think we should round the value to the upper value if it's a fraction, thanks for your response.